# Referencing code libraries stored in git without downloading them?

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab, versioning

I cannot find any straightforward answer as to if this is possible or not. Lets say I have a python application that I am versioning. Lets also say that I have some custom modules I have written that the application uses. Is it possible for me to reference the python modules that are on my gitlab server from my local code without having to download the modules? So that my environment would look like this:

```
                                            | Git (Gitlab) Server 
                                            |_____________________
                                            |Repository with python module
[Local PC with .py file]--------------------|
                                            |
```

Is this possible?

Comment: what do you mean by "reference"? I guess you can already download files you have on gitlab thru their URL; BTW you may cleanup you tags to let us know what it is really about...

Comment: By reference I mean point to the git repo and use the module within my local code WITHOUT downloading the module. Also my tags are relevant, I will not change them.

Comment: well git is designed to be distributed... actually you ask for mounting a remote directory aren't you?

Comment: That could be what I'm looking for, I would prefer to simply download the modules as its easier however my team has requested that I look into hosting modules on our git server so that we do not have to download them to run code they are used within.

Comment: Cheers thanks, that answers my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well to use the code you'll have to download it in a way or another, so you may implement some python frontend that would allow to download files "on demand" (and probably cache them), but in the end its always about downloading. Nevertheless you can probably avoid downloading the git "history" which might be huge. I you just want files, you may have a look to `git archive` command